# TestNG Parallel Test Configuration

Tags: java, maven-2, testng, java-6

With TestNG on Java 6 here's what I'd like to do in my Maven project:

1. Kick off a test method (`testAbc`) that can run multi-threaded using a queue-based `DataProvider`
2. Kick off a test that relies on `testAbc` (`testXyz`) after all the threads from `testAbc` complete

I thought I had it configured properly, but I do not.

Currently I have it configured as such:

```
@Test ( singleThreaded = false )
public class AutomatedTest {

  @Test (
    alwaysRun = true,
    dataProviderClass = UseCaseProvider.class,
    dataProvider = "getUseCasesNoDependencies",
    skipFailedInvocations = false,
    threadPoolSize = 25
  )
  public void testAbc(UseCase useCase) {
    executeUseCase(useCase);
  }

  @Test (
    dependsOnMethods = {"testAbc"},
    dataProviderClass = UseCaseProvider.class,
    dataProvider = "getUseCasesDependencies",
    singleThreaded = true
  )
  public void testXyz(UseCase useCase) {
    executeUseCase(useCase);
  }
}
```

All of the tests in `testAbc` that are provided by the `@DataProvider` take a long time to run but can be run up to 25 simultaneously (there's a good few hundred of them).  Everything in `testXyz` cannot be run in parallel as not only do all cases rely on `testAbc`, but the processing is just not friendly to thread pooling like that.

My Maven configuration is setup as follows:

```
<build>
  <plugins>
    <plugin>
      <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
      <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
      <configuration>
        <parallel>methods</parallel>
        <threadCount>25</threadCount>
      </configuration>
    </plugin>
  </plugins>
</build>
```

When I run `mvn -U test` I don't see my tests actually running in parallel.
Help!

```
$ mvn -version
Apache Maven 2.2.1 (r801777; 2009-08-06 15:16:01-0400)
Java version: 1.6.0_35
Java home: /System/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/1.6.0.jdk/Contents/Home
Default locale: en_US, platform encoding: MacRoman
OS name: "mac os x" version: "10.7.5" arch: "x86_64" Family: "mac"
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What about adding `threadPoolSize`

```
@Test ( singleThreaded = false, threadPoolSize = 5 )
public class AutomatedTest {
...
```

The `threadPoolSize` attribute allows you to specify how many threads should be allocated for this execution.

EDIT

Just noticed that you missed `invocationCount`. Please note that `threadPoolSize` is ignored if `invocationCount` is not specified.

So please try leaving class @Test as it is and update `testAbc`

```
  @Test (
    alwaysRun = true,
    dataProviderClass = UseCaseProvider.class,
    dataProvider = "getUseCasesNoDependencies",
    skipFailedInvocations = false,
    threadPoolSize = 25,
    invocationCount = 25
  )
  public void testAbc(UseCase useCase) {
    executeUseCase(useCase);
  }
```

Comment: I put that on my `testAbc` method - I tried on the overall class with the same result.

Comment: @Joe I just added info about `invocationCount` which is also required. Otherwise `threadPoolSize` is ignored.

Comment: I guess I will have to switch this away from using the `DataProvider` the way I originally had it.  If I use `invocationCount` won't the `DataProvider` be invoked only the specified number of times in the `invocationCount`?  Then I will miss Use Cases if they are added since the number is arbitrary.

Comment: OK, that's half way there.  Using the invocation count (I set it to 25) worked just fine and my tests ran in parallel.  However, it only ran 25 of them.  I guess I need to look into the annotation transformer to get it set properly (http://testng.org/doc/documentation-main.html#annotationtransformers)

Comment: And how many test cases do you have? Is it constant value of variable? If constant then I believe setting `invocationCount` to that value should work fine. I am not sure how to provide variable number of executions to `invocationCount` using `@Test` annotation.

Comment: invocationcount would mean u run the same test with the same data those many times i.e. run the same case with data1 25 times, then with data 2 25 times...is that what you want?  or do you want to run all data cases to run parallely?

Comment: I want all the cases to run parallel.  However, the DataProvider is implemented as a Queue, so it won't repeat the tests.

Comment: Using a `testng.xml` Suite configuration with an annotation transformer worked in cooperation with this.  However, due to the nature of the issue I think I am just going to use a little, internal thread pool.

Comment: @Tom - I notice that you are forking threads with BOTH maven and then also with TestNG (implied by how you wrote your answer). Are you sure you intended to do that or is that a mistake?  Am I the only person that noticed this?