# Set the delay time for each <test> in TestNG

Tags: java, testng

**First as info**: I put each `@Test` in a different class (so of course each class only has 1 `@Test` annotation).

Actually my goal is to want to rerun the same class with different parameter, but I want to run another class first beforehand.

I've tried to find many references that **TestNG** doesn't allow repeat of a class or a `@Test` method annotation in one `<test>`. The repeat provided is an `invocationCount` function, I see about `invocationCount`, but I can't achieve my goal with `invocationCount` because this function repeats a `@Test` at the same time and then I can run another `@Test`.

```
public class SimpleTest1 {
    @Test
    @Parameters({"acc"})
    public void historyTransfer(String acc) {
        System.out.println(new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm:ss").format(Calendar.getInstance().getTime()));
    }
}
```

```
public class SimpleTest2 {
    @Test
    @Parameters({"senderAcc", "beneficiaryAcc", "amount"})
    public void tranfer(String senderAcc, String beneficiaryAcc, String amount) {
        System.out.println(new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm:ss").format(Calendar.getInstance().getTime()));
    }
}
```

I imagine to run like bellow configuration:

```
<suite name="Suite">
    <test name="My Test" >
        <classes>
            <class name="com.SimpleTest1">
                <parameter name="acc" value="11111"></parameter>
            </class>
            <class name="com.SimpleTest2">
                <parameter name="senderAcc" value="11111"></parameter>
                <parameter name="beneficiaryAcc" value="22222"></parameter>
                <parameter name="amount" value="100"></parameter>
            </class>
            <class name="com.SimpleTest1">
                <parameter name="acc" value="22222"></parameter>
            </class>
        </classes>
    </test>
</suite>
```

But the above configuration didn't go as planned because the second `SimpleTest1` was not executed.

Then I tried running it in a separate `<test>` like bellow and success, but I'm facing new issue about delay time each `<test>`.

Run multiple `<test>` serially (not parallel) as follows:

```
<suite name="Suite">
    <test name="My Test1" >
        <classes>
            <class name="com.SimpleTest1">
                <parameter name="acc" value="11111"></parameter>
            </class>
        </classes>
    </test>
    <test name="My Test2" >
        <classes>
            <class name="com.SimpleTest2">
                <parameter name="senderAcc" value="11111"></parameter>
                <parameter name="beneficiaryAcc" value="22222"></parameter>
                <parameter name="amount" value="100"></parameter>
            </class>
        </classes>
    </test>
    <test name="My Test3" >
        <classes>
            <class name="com.SimpleTest1">
                <parameter name="acc" value="22222"></parameter>
            </class>
        </classes>
    </test>
</suite>
```

TestNG Maven dependency:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.testng</groupId>
    <artifactId>testng</artifactId>
    <version>7.0.0</version>
    <scope>compile</scope>
</dependency>
```

Surefire:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.22.2</version>
    <configuration>
        <suiteXmlFiles>
            <suiteXmlFile>testng.xml</suiteXmlFile>
        </suiteXmlFiles>
      </configuration>
</plugin>
```

**IDE :** Eclipse (Version: 2018-09 (4.9.0))

**OS :** macOS Mojave (Version 10.14.6)

**Output**:

```
[RemoteTestNG] detected TestNG version 7.0.0
22-12-2020 21:59:32
22-12-2020 21:59:47
22-12-2020 21:59:57

===============================================
Suite
Total tests run: 3, Passes: 3, Failures: 0, Skips: 0
===============================================
```

But after the first `<test>` is finished, there is a delay of about 10 seconds before the next `<test>` runs, as well as the next test.

**Note**: I thought this was a problem with the IDE (I use Eclipse), but it wasn't. I've tried running it in 2 ways, via the IDE and the command line, and give me same result about this delay issue.

Via command line using this command :

```
mvn clean test -Dsurefire.suiteXmlFiles=testng.xml
```

Is there any configuration to reduce the delay time above?

Comment: Please give people more information. We can help nothing without what did you do with SimpleTest

Comment: what are you running SimpleTest in both tests? try using `" verbose=”10"` in suite to get more details

Comment: @user7294900 contains only one @Test annotation with code `System.out.println("test");` only, nothing else. Is my question unclear?

Comment: Try to run with `<suite name="Suite" verbose="10">` , why you need to same test class in both tests? maybe the delay is loading your context every Test

Comment: @Tea I've updated the question for more information.

Comment: @frianH - I took a look at the source code of testng https://github.com/cbeust/testng - and didn't find any code delays for runining / executing the test. From your output  ```RemoteTestNG``` - though it seems you are using a plugin in your IDE to run your testng test - which are using https://github.com/testng-team/testng-remote library - this doesnt seem to be well maintained one as their build is failing on github. Can you try and run the tests outside of your IDE from command line directly via maven or gradle what ever you are using and let us know - how that goes ?

Comment: @vbn also I've tried run via command line with this command : `mvn clean test -Dsurefire.suiteXmlFiles=testng.xml` and give me same result about this delay issue. Just info, I'm using Eclipse IDE. I also thought maybe the problem was from the IDE, but it wasn't.

Comment: @frianH - so as I understand, your initial problem is that you are trying to solve is - to run 2 parametrized test, but before the second parametrized test runs, you want to run another test in between.  Does this sum up your original ask?  And by the way I tried your code in Intellij - works without a delay, so it seems to be specific to surefire and eclipse

Comment: @niharika_neo question updated for more detail. Your statement right `run 2 parametrized test, but before the second parametrized test runs, you want to run another test in between`. But I want have only 1 **public void historyTransfer** and only 1 **public void transfer**. Because the method I will reuse for many parameters based on data source which user selecting, in the above I make the issue to be simpler. Currently my code worked but with delay, because I can't achieve with first configuration. Please help me if you have idea, with first issue or second issue (delay issue). regards

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, a suite is not a test plan (could be a good feature request btw) but just a way to select tests. It means you can't define a dependency between tests. That's why having the same test class doesn't work (it should fail or create different instances).

As I understand your needs, the best way is to separate your own logic and its integration with the test framework:

1. design your helper/fixture classes as you want:

_

```
public class SimpleClass1 {
  public void historyTransfer(String acc) {
    System.out.println(new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm:ss").format(Calendar.getInstance().getTime()));
  }
}

public class SimpleClass2 {
  public void tranfer(String senderAcc, String beneficiaryAcc, String amount) {
    System.out.println(new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm:ss").format(Calendar.getInstance().getTime()));
  }
}
```

2. define the classes for the integration with the test framework

_

```
public class SimpleTest {
  @Test
  @Parameters({"acc"})
  public void step1(String acc) {
    (new SimpleClass1()).historyTransfer(acc);
  }

  @Test(dependsOnMethods = {"step1"})
  @Parameters({"senderAcc", "beneficiaryAcc", "amount"})
  public void step2(String senderAcc, String beneficiaryAcc, String amount) {
    (new SimpleClass2()).transfer(acc);
  }

  @Test(dependsOnMethods = {"step2"})
  @Parameters({"acc"})
  public void step3(String acc) {
    (new SimpleClass1()).historyTransfer(acc);
  }
}
```

And the suite with the expected parameters:

```
<suite name="Suite">
  <test name="My Test" >
    <classes>
        <class name="com.SimpleTest">
            <methods>
              <include name="step1">
              <parameter name="acc" value="11111"></parameter>
            </methods>
            <methods>
              <include name="step2">
              <parameter name="senderAcc" value="11111"></parameter>
              <parameter name="beneficiaryAcc" value="22222"></parameter>
              <parameter name="amount" value="100"></parameter>
            </methods>
            <methods>
              <include name="step3">
              <parameter name="acc" value="22222"></parameter>
            </methods>
        </class>
    </classes>
  </test>
</suite>
```

(disclaimer: I didn't check the XML against the dtd, could be wrong but you have the idea)

The naming or the way to create fixtures depends on your own conventions.

Comment: Hi @juherr thanks for this answer. Btw can you help me again for another issue, if you have time and deign please visit this thread : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65611216/why-testng-doesnt-allow-to-repeat-class

Answer (score 1):

You can set priority or dependency on other method using the annotations as described here:

https://testng.org/doc/documentation-main.html#annotations

check for @Test.priority or @Test.dependsOnMethods

Doing this, will allow you run the tests one after the other serially.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, but this answer doesn't answer the question yet :)

Comment: ah ok - you want to reduce the delay between the test runs - you are already running the tests serially ? in that case ignore the above answer...

Comment: are sure the delay in execution is due to TestNG scheduling and not due to some prior test setup configured in your test suites / cases - can you provide more details on your test cases ?

Comment: Hi, I've updated the question for more information.

Comment: That's great, can you also provide the output / logs  - from where you deduce that testng is pausing for 10s between the test runs.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know why you need to run same test class in separate tests, but when starting test it may load all relevant context which maybe take time and maybe after test end it may need to close some resources, both may take time/[few seconds](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44266905/how-to-speed-up-the-starting-time-of-testng-tests-in-eclipse)

You can use [verbose](https://dheerajgambhir.medium.com/the-use-of-verbose-attribute-in-testng-or-pom-xml-maven-surefire-plugin-2ddae842dd9b) to use more details of the cause of the delay (and add more logs to view timing)

```
<suite name="Suite" verbose="10">
```

> The verbosity level is 0 to 10, where 10 is most detailed.
> Once you set it to 10, you’ll see that console output will contain information regarding the tests, methods, and listeners, etc.

To speed the process you can also use TestNG's [parallel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14267528/testng-parallel-test-configuration) feature

> The threadPoolSize attribute allows you to specify how many threads should be allocated for this execution.

Comment: Apologies, thanks for your answer, but I think I should update the question to better explain what issue I'm facing currently.

Comment: Hi, I've updated the question for more information.

Comment: @frianH did you add verbose=10 and saw there the time is spent?

Comment: Yes, have tried `verbose=10` and I got same result (around 10s) each `<test>` :(
Log into more detail.