# Using DataProvider by initializing WebDriver one time within TestNG

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, testng, dataprovider

I'm trying to check login page control by using dataprovider but i don't want to initialize webdriver  again and again for each username password control. Once i come into login page, checking all concerned scenarios on login page in single time without starting another driver seems more convenient to me but i couldn't figure it out. When running following code, data[0][0] and data[0][1] is being  correctly checked but it gives no such element on Login method having second priority test annotation when being tried to be typed data[1][0] and data[1][1]. Probably, it causes because driver is not looking at that page on that time. How can I handle this issue ?

error:

```
org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"//div[@class='q-input-wrapper email-input']//input[@class='q-input']"}
```

code:

```
    public class TestCaseFirst {
    
    public WebDriver driver;
    
    @BeforeTest
    public void Start() throws InterruptedException {
        
        WebDriverManager.chromedriver().setup();
        driver= new ChromeDriver();
        driver.get("https://www.faxzas.com/");
        driver.manage().window().maximize();
        Thread.sleep(2000);}
        
    @Test(priority=1)
    public void RoadtoLogin() throws InterruptedException {
        
        driver.findElement(By.xpath("//a[@title='Close']")).click();
        Thread.sleep(1000);
        driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@class='login-container']//span[@id='not-logged-in-container']")).click();;
        Thread.sleep(1000);
    }
    
    
    @Test(dataProvider="loginInfos", priority=2)
    public void Login(String mail, String password) throws InterruptedException {
        
        driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@class='q-input-wrapper email-input']//input[@class='q-input']")).sendKeys(mail);
        Thread.sleep(1000);
        driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@class='q-input-wrapper']//input[@class='q-input']")).sendKeys(password);
        Thread.sleep(1000);
        driver.findElement(By.xpath("//button[@type='submit']")).click();
        Thread.sleep(1000);
        String description = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@id='error-box-wrapper']//span[@class='message']")).getText();
        System.out.println(description);
    }
    
    
    @DataProvider(name="loginInfos")
    public Object[][] getData(){
        
        Object[][] data = new Object[6][2];
        data[0][0]="blackkfredo@gmail.com"; 
        data[0][1]=""; 
        data[1][0]="blackkfredo@gmail.com";
        data[1][1]="443242"; 
        data[2][0]=""; 
        data[2][1]="1a2b3c4d";
        data[3][0]="";
        data[3][1]=""; 
        data[4][0]="blackkfredogmail.com"; 
        data[4][1]="1a2b3c4d"; 
        data[5][0]="blackkfredo@gmail.com"; 
        data[5][1]="1a2b3c4d"; 
        
        return data;
    }
}
```

Comment: Your question is not clear on what exactly each method wants to do - roadToLogin has to be executed only once?

Answer (score 0):

You need to reset your page to the login page where you are expecting the element to be.  Either put an @AfterMethod and go back to the page you are trying to test or put an @BeforeMethod for the same. You may even want to wrap up your find element calls and handle the exceptions by going back to the main page.

Comment: Hi @niharika_neo, can you help my post here : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65285018/set-the-delay-time-for-each-test-in-testng
thanks advance